# What fanless ATI Radeon cards work with the open-source drivers?

Tags: 10.04, drivers, ati, radeon

I am building four Intel Core i5 desktop systems. The systems should run Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and be used for watching HD movies, Youtube etc. not for gaming. I want to use fanless ATI Radeon cards and the open source driver.

What fanless ATI Radeon graphics cards are well supported by the open source driver(s) and Ubuntu 10.04 LTS?

Comment: You can probably find more information on the open-source Radeon driver, as well as hardware compatibility information, here at this [Ubuntu Documentation page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver).

Answer (score 1):

I am using a Sapphire fan-less card on my system, its not top of the notch and its a bit outdated but that only means you wont have problem with drivers ;)

If you are not interested in running Crysis on your system and you just want a card that can handle anything thrown at it (games, films, external monitors, HDMI connections) and doesn't make a sound when your using it this might be a good option and the current price is well affordable.

Have a look here:
http://www.sapphiretech.com/presentation/product/?leg=&psn=000101&pid=352

If you want to look for one yourself I would say that the open source driver will work on anything on the compatible list (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver) the only issue really if finding a good designed fan-less card.

Answer (score 0):

[Radeon HD 5450](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-5000/hd-5450-overview/pages/hd-5450-overview.aspx) is very popular choice for that kind of systems and it works perfectly well with Linux open source drivers. Had one of these in my system running Ubuntu 10.04.